# Implementing an Interface at Runtime

Tags: c#, .net

Is it possible to make an already compiled class implement a certain interface at run time, an example:

```
public interface ISomeInterface {
    void SomeMethod();
}

public class MyClass {
    // this is the class which i want to implement ISomeInterface at runtime
}
```

is this possible, if yes then how ?

Comment: No. Why would you want to do this?

Comment: You can't make MyClass implement ISomeInterface, but you could generate a class that derives from MyClass and implement ISomeInterface, using Reflection.Emit or some other technique.

Comment: You could use the technique suggested by @ThomasLevesque, but if you give us your use case, there's probably a better way to achieve waht you want

Comment: @TyCobb: Why are you implying that there is no good reason to do this? Even though C# does not support this type of polymorphism, it's a good and valid idea. For instance, type classes in Haskell or Clojure's protocols (IIRC) work that way.

Comment: @stakx I didn't mean to imply that. I really do want to know why one would do this instead of implementing the interface.

Comment: @TyCobb, because i work with WPF and i thought why not make my view model implement IDataErrorInfo at run time and make that run time implementation use for example data annotations on the view model so i don't have to do that over and over and force my self into using a view model base.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well almost. You can use impromptu-interface.

https://github.com/ekonbenefits/impromptu-interface

Basic example from https://github.com/ekonbenefits/impromptu-interface/wiki/UsageBasic :

```
using ImpromptuInterface;

public interface ISimpleClassProps
{
  string Prop1 { get;  }
  long Prop2 { get; }
  Guid Prop3 { get; }
}

var tAnon = new {Prop1 = "Test", Prop2 = 42L, Prop3 = Guid.NewGuid()};
var tActsLike = tAnon.ActLike<ISimpleClassProps>();
```

Comment: Oh, very nice... I didn't know that library, but I'll keep it in mind just in case.

Comment: truly great, this is possibly the closest answer to correctness but i will give this question some time to see if there is even a better way. Edit: this really looks very promising as the project description seems is targeting the exact areas i am looking for.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `Adapter` pattern to make it appear your implementing the interface. This would look somewhat like this:

```
public interface ISomeInterface {
    void SomeMethod();
}

public class MyClass {
    // this is the class which i want to implement ISomeInterface at runtime
}

public SomeInterfaceAdapter{
    Myclass _adaptee;
    public SomeInterfaceAdapter(Myclass adaptee){
        _adaptee = adaptee;
    }
    void SomeMethod(){
        // forward calls to adaptee
        _adaptee.SomeOtherMethod();
    }
}
```

Using this would look somewhat like this:

```
Myclass baseobj = new Myclass();
ISomeInterface obj = new SomeInterfaceAdapter(baseobj);
obj.SomeMethod();
```